# How can i load images in django template with asynchronous system?

Tags: javascript, html, django, asynchronous, django-channels

I was trying to make asynchronous system in django. I've used Channels for this purpose, and i was trying to send the image url to my template and display the image on the template page. But it didn't work.

Here is my settings.py file

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

import os
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), ) 
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' 
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Here is how i send the data from the database.

```
 class WSConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
        def connect(self):
            self.accept()
            x = Student.objects.filter(id=1)
            self.send(json.dumps({
                    'name':x[0].name,
                    "img":x[0].image.url,
                    }))
```

index.html file

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>


<div id='img'></div>

    <script>
        
        var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000/ws/some_url/');
        
        socket.onmessage = function(event)
        {
             var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
             console.log(data);

         var url = data.img
         var el = document.getElementById("img");
         el.innerHTML=`<img src= ${url}>`;
        }
       </script>
</body>
```

All the asynchronous system works perfectly.The js is already getting the image but it's not displaying the image but the other data.

Answer (score -1):

The error was that i put the media url path to the app urls.py file. It must be in the project urls.py file.